# Marcus, Number Fields, problem 5(b), Chapter 4

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group G. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of K (that is, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ of L). We assume that $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in every intermediate field, but not totally ramified in $L$. We have to prove that no intermediate fields can exist. I think I have a proof. It would be helpful if someone could check my arguments and reassure me that everything is ok (assuming of course that my proof is correct).

So let $M$ be an intermediate field (we assume that $K \subsetneq M \subsetneq L$). It's true that there exists a prime $\mathfrak{q}'$ of $M$ such that $\mathfrak{q}'$ lies over $\mathfrak{p}$. It's also true that there exists a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $L$ such that $\mathfrak{q}$ lies over $\mathfrak{q}'$. Of course this implies that $\mathfrak{q}$ lies over $\mathfrak{p}$. Hence, it makes sense to talk about the ramification index of $\mathfrak{q}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$: $e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p} )$. Using the multiplicativity of the ramification indices we have that $$ e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})= e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') \hspace{1mm} e(\mathfrak{q}' \mid \mathfrak{p}). \hspace{10mm} (1) $$ By assumption, $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $M$ and therefore $e(\mathfrak{q}' \mid \mathfrak{p})=[M:K]$. Thus relationship $(1)$ becomes $$e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})= e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') \hspace{1mm} [M:K] .\hspace{10mm} (2) $$ IF we had that $e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}')=[L:M]$ then from $(2)$ we would have that $ e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p}) = [L:K] $, which is wrong because we assumed that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not totally ramified in $L$. Therefore, in order to get our contradiction we have to prove that $e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}')=[L:M]$.

The extension $L/M$ is Galois and hence (look (for example) Theorem 21 by Marcus) $$ [L:M] = r' \hspace{1mm} e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') \hspace{1mm} f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') ,\hspace{10mm} (3) $$ where by $f(\mid)$ I denote the inertial degree and by $r'$ the number of primes of $\mathcal{O}_L$ that lie above $\mathfrak{q}'$. We shall prove that $r'$ and $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}')$ are both equal to 1.

Consider the inertia field $L_E$ and it's prime $\mathfrak{q}_E$ (which lies above $\mathfrak{p}$ and under $\mathfrak{q}$). We know (look (for example) Theorem 28 by Marcus) that $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})= f(\mathfrak{q}_E \mid \mathfrak{p} )$. But, by assumption, $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $L_E$ and hence $f(\mathfrak{q}_E \mid \mathfrak{p})=1$. Therefore, $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})=1$. Using now the multiplicativity of the inertial degrees we have: $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})=f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') \hspace{1mm} f(\mathfrak{q}' \mid \mathfrak{p}) $. That is, $1=f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}') \hspace{1mm} f(\mathfrak{q}' \mid \mathfrak{p}) $. Of course, this implies that $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}')=1$, which is what we wanted.

Now we show that $r'=1$. Let's write $r$ for the number of primes of $\mathcal{O}_L$ tha lie above $\mathfrak{p}$. It's obvious that $r=1 \implies r'=1$. So we show that $r=1$. We have, $\mathfrak{p}$ totally ramified in $L_E \implies e(\mathfrak{q}_E \mid \mathfrak{p})=[L_E:K]$. But we know (look (for example) Theorem 28 by Marcus) that $[L_E:K]=r \hspace{1mm} f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})$. Above, we already showed that $f(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{p})=1$. Therefore, $[L_E:K]=r$. Hence, $e(\mathfrak{q}_E \mid \mathfrak{p})=r$. But we know (look (for example) Theorem 28 by Marcus) that $e(\mathfrak{q}_E \mid \mathfrak{p})=1$. Hence, $r=1$. So, $r'=1$.

The above yield: $[L:M]=e(\mathfrak{q} \mid \mathfrak{q}')$. As we already explained, this leads us to a contradiction.

If something doesn't make sense please tell me. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think that’s correct but there’s a way to present the proof in a shorter way?

Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime in $L$ over $\mathfrak{p}$; let $I$ be the inertia group. If $I$ is the trivial subgroup, then $\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{q}/\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified so (as subextensions are ramified) there cannot be any subextension of $L/K$.

Assume $I$ is not the trivial subgroup (unramified extension, so it forces that $L/K$ without subextension). Let $M=L^I$. It’s an intermediate field smaller than $L$, so $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $M$. Let $\mathfrak{q’}=\mathfrak{q} \cap M$, so $e(\mathfrak{q}’:\mathfrak{p})=[M:K]$.

But the Galois group of $L/M$ is the inertia group of $\mathfrak{q}$, so that $[L:M]=e(\mathfrak{q}:\mathfrak{q’})$. It follows $[L:K]=e(\mathfrak{q}:\mathfrak{p})$, which concludes.